# Cannot read property 'fragment' of undefined

Tags: javascript, parcel, svelte

I'm trying to nest one svelte component in another svelte component.

```
//index.js
import Parent from './Parent.svelte';

new Parent({
  target: document.querySelector('main')
})


// Parent.svelte
<script>
  import Child from "./Child.svelte";
</script>

<p>parent component</p>
<Child />


// Child.svelte
<p>child component</p>
```

I expect Child.svelte to be nested in Parent.svelte, but I get this error message instead

`Cannot read property 'fragment' of undefined`

by the way: I´m using parcel with parcel-plugin-svelte

Comment: The `<main>` element probably doesn't exist by the time this is called.

Comment: @Lewis the <main> element exists. it is hard-coded into the index.html file. This will run if I remove the nested child

Comment: when using [REPL on their site](https://svelte.dev/repl) your sample works to me. could your reproduce full set up in codesandbox or something similar?

Comment: Same issue here when I try to add a child component. The issue goes away if I `parcel build` instead of `parcel watch` so I suspect parcel is doing something odd in dev builds

Comment: Its a confirmed bug: https://github.com/DeMoorJasper/parcel-plugin-svelte/issues/55#issuecomment-508411959

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug with `parcel-svelte-plugin`. The workaround for now as per [github issue #55](https://github.com/DeMoorJasper/parcel-plugin-svelte/issues/55) is to disable parcel `hmr`:

```sh
parcel --no-hmr
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue and need to change the way how react is imported

```
 import { React } from 'react'
```

need to change to

```
 import React from 'react'
```